# Tomcat background processing

Tags: java, tomcat, task

I am using Tomcat 9.0 to run Java code on some data from a database.
I have a single servlet that is invoked by directly accessing x.x.x.x:8080/myapp/myservlet.
The length of time to complete is between 5 seconds - 1 minute.

The servlet returns a response right away, leaving it to continue processing in the background. I am not sure Tomcat is supposed to be used like this.
The problem is until the processing has actually finished, the web client cannot access x.x.x.x:8080/myapp/myservlet.

Each new web client can connect and invoke the servlet fine.

I simply want to invoke my java code as a background process in a fire and forget manner. Is this possible with Tomcat?

Any guidance would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move you code in a Thread or an executor and use the servlet only to start and monitor the execution.

```
public class myservlet extends HttpServlet
{
...
Thread t = null;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    if(t == null || !t.isAlive())
    {
        t = new Thread(new Runner());
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        out.write("Process started.\n");
    }
    else
        out.write("Process running...\n");
}

public static class Runner implements Runnable
{
  public void run()
  {
    // put your code here
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola for your response.

I was under the impression that it not good to create threads within a servlet.
I am new to Tomcat, even servlets in general, but I thought Tomcat handled the requests and initialised a new thread based on it internal thread pool.

My logs show multiple threads working fine (when multiple clients connect at the same time).

My issue is since my Java code can be long running, it blocks further requests from the same client until the previous request has completed.

Comment: That's precisely why you'd move the code in question to a different thread. In general you're right: don't start new threads excessively, rather utilize a thread pool. But the principle solution is to decouple your processing from the http handling thread

Comment: Thanks Olaf, this helps me further my understanding